# Azure DevOps - Planning of manual testing in Test Plans - how to define planned execution date for each Test case

Tags: azure-devops

At our project we use Azure DevOps Test Plans for manual testing. We do not use pipelines. We have each Test plan for testing of one iteration - approx. 1 month testing for each test plan, but eg. SIT or UAT will take longer. I would like to see, when each test case (or test suite) is going to be tested, but there is no attribute for this.
I would also like to have reporting based on that (how many test cases should have been run by today and how many were really run)?
Can anyone help how to approach that?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple way, you can use iterations to plan target periods for your test activities. If you want to have a custom attribute, you can edit your process template ([Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops)):

1. Select Add new field:
   [image]
2. As an example, assign the exiting field to the test case:
   [image]

You can add it to the test suite and test case:

Test case:

[image]

Test suite:

[image]

Comment: Hello Aleksander, thank you for really quick answer. We already have added the custom field for the project, but the problem is, that we want to test several times (eg. regression tests...) and for that I need to have this date on the "Test Plan x Test Case" entity (Test point I could say?). is that possible? Thank you

Comment: @JanaMacháčková, yes that's an issue. I saw one solution with several fields `Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.SubjectMatterExpert1 …Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.SubjectMatterExpert3`. You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/cmmi/guidance-requirements-field-reference-cmmi?view=azure-devops. In this case, you can use Date1, Date2, Date3.

Comment: Hi Aleksander, I am not sure, if I got it right. Are you suggesting to use more customized "Date" fields at the "Test Case" work item entity? I do not find this very suitable, because we do not know, how many times we want to test.  I would think, that  the "Planned execution date" would be somewhere at the same location as the field "Tester", I just could not find it in the setup. Would you know?

Comment: @JanaMacháčková, I agree, that`s not very suitable. There is no planned date for test cases, the planning period is an iteration (with sprint start and finish date) without any specific date for test cases..... As an additional workaround, you can assign Task to a tester, set the planned date, and link to the corresponding test cases.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksander. We will think it through.